# Javascript looping fader animation

Tags: javascript, dom, easing

Here's a small module I've written that implements an animation which fades through the child elements in a container div on a continual loop.

I realise I could have done this way quicker using JQuery, but I wanted to write it from scratch in this case.

The module works well enough, but I'd be very grateful for any comments on the code.

```
(function() {

    function fade(e, duration, direction, /* 'in', 'out' */ easing, /* func */ complete /* callback */) {

        // Set default values for parameters
        if (easing === undefined) easing = linear;
        if (complete === undefined) complete = function(){};

        // initialise counter values
        var percentComplete = 0;
        var opacity = parseFloat(e.style.opacity);
        if (opacity < 0) opacity = 0;
        if (opacity > 1) opacity = 1;

        // initialise values that stay constant throughout execution
        var startOpacity = opacity;
        var framerate = 60;
        var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();

        function animate() {
            if (percentComplete >= 1.0) {
                return complete();
            }

            var elapsedTime = (new Date()).getTime() - startTime;
            percentComplete = elapsedTime / duration;

            var easing_options = {elapsedTime: elapsedTime, endValue: 1, totalDuration: duration}

            if (direction === "in") {
                easing_options.startValue = startOpacity;
                opacity = easing(easing_options);
            }
            else if (direction === 'out') {
                easing_options.startValue = 1 - startOpacity;
                opacity = 1 - easing(easing_options); 
            };
            e.style.opacity = opacity;
            setTimeout(animate, 1000/framerate);
        }

        setTimeout(animate, 1000/framerate);
    };

    function fadeIn(e, duration, easing, complete) {
        fade(e, duration, 'in', easing, complete);
    }

    function fadeOut(e, duration, easing, complete) {
        fade(e, duration, 'out', easing, complete);
    };

    // default easing function
    var linear = function(options) {
        var elapsedTime = options.elapsedTime;
        var startValue = options.startValue;
        var endValue = options.endValue;
        var totalDuration = options.totalDuration;

        var difference = endValue - startValue;

        var result = startValue + ((elapsedTime / totalDuration) * difference)

        return result
    };

    // Utility. Bidirectional circular iterator.
    function Cycle(arraylike) {
        this.values = arraylike;
        this.index = null;
    }
    Cycle.prototype._resetIndex = function() {
        this.index = this.index % this.values.length;
    };
    Cycle.prototype.next = function() {
        if (this.index === null) {
            this.index = 0;
        }
        else {
            this.index += 1;
            this._resetIndex();
        }
        return this.values[this.index]
    };
    Cycle.prototype.previous = function() {

        this.index = (this.index === null ? 0 : this.index) + (this.values.length - 1)
        this._resetIndex();
        return this.values[this.index];
    };
    Cycle.prototype.current = function() {
        return (this.index !== null ? this.values[this.index] : this.next())
    };


    // The main fader constructor. Fades through the child elements of a
    // container div on a continual loop.
    function Fader(options /* container, fadeLength, pauseLength */) {
        this.container = document.getElementById(options.container);
        var ch = this.container.children

        // Initialise opacity and position for child Elements of the
        // container div
        ch[0].style.opacity = 1;
        ch[0].style.position = "absolute";
        ch[0].style.top = "0px";
        ch[0].style.left = "0px";

        for (i = 1; i < ch.length; i++) {
            ch[i].style.opacity = 0;
            ch[i].style.position = "absolute";
            ch[i].style.top = "0px";
            ch[i].style.left = "0px";
        }

        this.slides = new Cycle(ch);
        this.fadeLength = options.fadeLength;
        this.pauseLength = options.pauseLength;
    }

    Fader.prototype.start = function() {
        var self = this;
        var fadeLength = this.fadeLength;
        var pauseLength = this.pauseLength;
        setTimeout(function() {
            fadeOut(self.slides.next(), fadeLength);
            fadeIn(self.slides.next(), fadeLength);
            self.timer = setInterval(function() {
                fadeOut(self.slides.current(), fadeLength);
                fadeIn(self.slides.next(), fadeLength);
            }, fadeLength + pauseLength)
        }, pauseLength);
    };

    Fader.prototype.stop = function() {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
        this.slides.previous();
    };

    // Exported object
    var exports = {
        fadeIn: fadeIn,
        fadeOut: fadeOut,
        noConflict: noConflict,
        Fader: Fader
    };

    // Mechanism to remove naming conflicts if another module exports
    // the name Fader
    var noConflictName = window['fadeLib'];
    function noConflict() {
        window['fadeLib'] = noConflictName;
        return exports;
    }

    // Export public interface
    window['fadeLib'] = exports;

})();
```

Here's a html snippet showing how the module is used.

```
<body>

    <div id="container" style="position:absolute; left:100px; width:500px;">
        <h1 style="color:red;">Hello world!</h1>
        <h1 style="color:red;">Goodbye!</h1>
        <h1 style="color:red;">Farewell!</h1>
    </div>

    <script src="faderLib.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("load", function() {
            var fader = new fadeLib.Fader({container: "container", fadeLength: 5000, pauseLength: 5000});
            fader.start();
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Available for fiddling @ http://jsfiddle.net/vudC2/ (with a 2-second delay because I am impatient)

Comment: does `Cycle` really need that much complexity? Why do you set `style.top, style.left` to `0px`?

Comment: `Cycle.Next` and `Cycle.Previous` use different idioms [is that the right word?] for basically the same code. Although Cycle.Previous makes an invariant call to `_resetIndex`

Comment: I suppose its not strictly necessary for the purpose at hand. But it seemed like a generally useful pattern. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "different idioms for the same code" in this case. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I added my thoughts about mixed idioms, below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small changes:

Cache the length, and set the invariants only once:

```
    // Initialise opacity and position for child Elements of the
    // container div
    for (var i = 0, l = ch.length; i < l; i++) {
        ch[i].style.opacity = 0;
        ch[i].style.position = "absolute";
        ch[i].style.top = "0px";
        ch[i].style.left = "0px";
    }

    // only first element is visible
    ch[0].style.opacity = 1;
```

Multiple coding idioms in the Cycle object:
clear `if...else` in `.next` changes to a ternary op and an invariant call to `.resetIndex` in `.previous`, and change to _resetIndex to handle negative movement.

```
Cycle.prototype._resetIndex = function() {
    this.index = this.index % this.values.length;
};
Cycle.prototype.next = function() {
    if (this.index === null) {
        this.index = 0;
    }
    else {
        this.index += 1; 
        this._resetIndex();
    }
    return this.values[this.index]
};
Cycle.prototype.previous = function() {

    this.index = (this.index === null ? 0 : this.index) + (this.values.length - 1)
    this._resetIndex();
    return this.values[this.index];
};
```

change to (perhaps):

```
Cycle.prototype._resetIndex = function() {
    this.index = (this.index + this.values.length) % this.values.length;
};

Cycle.prototype.next = function() {
    if (this.index === null) {
        this.index = 0;
    }
    else {
        this.index++;
        this._resetIndex();
    }
    return this.values[this.index]
};

Cycle.prototype.previous = function() {

    if (this.index === null) {
        this.index = (this.values.length - 1);
    }
    else {
        this.index--;
        this._resetIndex();
    }

    return this.values[this.index];
};
```

Comment: Thanks. That clarifies your mixed idioms idioms comment. However, I believe there is a small error in the 'previous' method. For example, in a nodelist on length 6, where this.index starts at 3, calling previous would make this.index = 2 + (5 - 1) = 7. _resetIndex would then make this index 1, where we want index 2. I think the solution is just to say this.index += this.values.length - 1, and then call this,_resetIndex.

Comment: I hadn't actually tried out the code, so fiddled with it a bit. Similar idioms can happen if we make a tweak to the _resetIndex method. Now next() and previous() are so similar it suggests some more refactoring might be possible (only the initial element on index === null and increment/decrement are different).